# Spring Aggregation Framework: How to create nested $divide, $subtract, $mod query?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to create a `ProjectionOperation` in the Java Spring aggregation framework. The following simplified raw mongo db query works fine and should be implemented with java code.

I'm struggling with the first row in the $project section of my query. How can I write nested project queries in the aggregation framework? (side note: `startTime` is a fixed and given unix timestamp)

```
db.procedure_executions.aggregate([
{ $match : { 
        "application.$id" : ObjectId("55144929bc26f48fb5de15a7")
    }
},
{ $project : { 
    'startTimeGrouping' : { '$subtract' : [ { $divide : ["$startTime", 3600 ]}, { $mod : [{ $divide : ["$startTime", 3600 ]},1] } ] },
    'caller': "$procedure.annotations.members.caller",
    'callee': "$procedure.annotations.members.callee"
    } 
},
{ $group : {
    _id : { 
        startTimeGrouping : "$startTimeGrouping", 
        caller: "$caller",         
        callee: "$callee" 
    }, 
    'count' : { '$sum' : 1}
  }
 }
 ]);
```

I started like this:

```
final ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = project()
         .and(CALLER).as(CALLER_ATTRIBUTE)
         .and(CALLEE).as(CALLEE_ATTRIBUTE)
...
```

but I have no idea how to nest multiple $divide, $mod, $subtract, etc.

Basically, I have to subtract:

```
.and('startTime').divide(3600).mod(1)
```

from

```
.and('startTime').divide(3600)
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use SpEL like:

`.andExpression("(startTime / 3600) - ((startTime / 3600) % 1")`